# Did demons and other supernatural creatures definitely exist?

Tags: sources-mekorot, sheidim-demons

There are plenty of stories in various Jewish sources of demons and other supernatural creatures, and I've only ever heard these taken at face value.  Does everyone agree that these creatures really existed, or are there opinions that they are metaphorical?

According to the opinions that they do exist, does anyone discuss what their function is?  *Malachim* are created to be agents of Hashem, but what's the point in these other beings if they exist?

Comment: @bondonk Partly, but not entirely - do the answers there apply to other supernatural creatures as well - eg. golems?  Also it doesn't answer the second part of the question

Comment: This does add to it though - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31570/why-does-god-tolerate-demons-what-is-their-purpose?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Rav Hutner said *sheidim* are the world (earth) dreaming.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE do you have any explanation of what that actually means?

Comment: It probably means that reality isn't as hard cut as you think it is and there is an area of corporeal existence which slips in and out of the realm of our understanding.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE since I tend to think of the Universe as a simulation that Hashem is running, kind of Matrix style, I'm not sure that I think of it as being hard cut at all!